# Geometrical Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence $U(n)$ with $U(n+1) = f(U(n))$ with $f(x) = ax+b$.

I'm supposed to express $U(n)$ as a function dependant on $n$. 
Doing so with an auxiliary sequence $V(n) = U(n) - ɑ$.
Where $ɑ$ is the solution to $f(x) = x$. Also I have to prove that $V(n)$ is geometric.

I don't know where to start on that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $a\not=1$. Since we have
$$U_{n+1}-\frac{b}{1-a}=a\left(U_n-\frac{b}{1-a}\right),$$
we have
$$V_{n+1}=aV_n$$
where $V_n=U_n-\frac{b}{1-a}$ is geometric.